# What is the best solution for accessing to android room DB with multiple interface?

Tags: android, android-room

I have room database which is from some library that I don't want to modify but I have to access that DB. And that library already implemented with interface to access room DB with livedata and viewmodels. When accessing to android room DB, it requires interface.(according to the documentation, it has to extends "RoomDatabase") But problem is from that library I can't access to the DB through the interface.
So my plan is make another interface(extends RoomDatabase) to access that DB. I'm not sure but I think this is not general way of using room database.
Are there any critical issues would expect if I use like that or any other way to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use a factory with singleton instance to inside your database. Thus you can access your DB everywhere without creating any extra DB's instance.

This is my code using Kotlin, but I think the ideas are same in Kotlin and Java

```
@Database(entities = [Address::class], version = 1)
abstract class AppDatabase : RoomDatabase() {
    abstract fun addressDao(): AddressDao

    companion object{
        private var INSTANCE: AppDatabase? = null

        fun getInstance(context: Context) = INSTANCE ?:
        Room.databaseBuilder(context, AppDatabase::class.java, "MyDatabaseName")
            // .allowMainThreadQueries()
            .build().also { INSTANCE = it }
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry for not uploading my code, but this code already implemented on library which I can't access directly. If I modify I can access but I don't want to do that.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion you can create a BaseDatabase class that will extends the RoomDatabase

```
 // Base Database class
 public abstract class BaseDatabase extends RoomDatabase {

 }

// create your class that extends BaseDatabase
@Database(..)
public abstract class AppDatabase extends BaseDatabase {

}
```